# Can we use the Gini corefficient to calculate the standard deviation of an income distribution?

Tags: econometrics, gini

I have a question regarding the Gini coefficient.

I want to know how I can calculate the $\%$ of people earning $x\$$ or less for a population in a country with a given mean income level.

I know one can calculate this from a probability density function with a given mean and standard deviation. Data exist on mean income levels and Gini coefficients by country so I am wondering if there is some way to use the Gini to derive the standard deviation.